# Input and Display unicode characters in jTextField

Tags: java, unicode, utf-8, jtextfield

I have java GUI program for input and display text in database but I keep on getting question marks for non-english characters in jTextField when I retrieve back from database.

For input I can just copy/paste non English characters to textfield and it displays correctly (when pasted). Also database insert goes fine without any error. Since java is Unicode based, I was expecting to go this smoothly.

### Other information that might help

### Development Environment

OS: Windows XP with all non-english character support installed

### Java

JDK 1.6 update23

### Backend

MySQL 5.5

Encoding: utf8

Collation: utf8_general_ci

Though my application is in English, I want to be able to input and display the utf8 characters in the fields. Need some suggestion.

Comment: Also I have used "useunicode=true" and "characterEncoding=UTF-8" in my Connector/J but problem still remains same

Comment: First check that what comes back from the db is, indeed, non-English text. (Display the hex for each char, for instance.) If that's verified, then it may be a font issue.

Comment: I checked with php page and indeed the data was not stored correctly in mysql. The input I made previously was without unicode in connector/j. Using "useunicode=true" and "characterEncoding=UTF-8" in my connection string solved the problem with input and output. Thanks

Comment: I had a similar problem. I could insert unicode chars with insert query but when I type some in the Jtextfield and press add button they were inserted to db corrupted. Editing the connection string to jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/vt?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8 solved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem. I could insert unicode chars with insert query but when I type some in the Jtextfield and press add button they were inserted to db corrupted. Editing the connection string solved my problem.

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/databasename?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In eclipse, Windows > Preferences > Java > Installed JRE > Select the JRE > 
Click on Edit button > set value for Default VM arguments > 

-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

Then compile the source file and execute the program. 

If you want to display UTF-8 characters at console then therefor it, 
while running an application follow these steps.

Right Click > Run As > Run > Java Application > 
EXE Name of Java Application which you are trying to run > 
Click on Tab Common > Console Encoding > Other > UTF-8 > Apply > Run
```